# Do either of $c\cdot I_n-A$ or $A-c\cdot I_n$ have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and let $c$ be a scalar. The matrices $c\cdot I_n-A$ and $A-c\cdot I_n$ are used to say interesting things about $A$. Do either of $c\cdot I_n-A$ and $A-c\cdot I_n$ have a name?

It seems like calling $A-c\cdot I_n$ something like the "shift of $A$ by a factor of $c$" makes sense, but "shift matrices" usually refer to binary matrices whose only nonzero entries are either on the superdiagonal or subdiagonal.

I suppose it's also worth asking if either of $c\cdot I-T$ or $T-c\cdot I$ have a name if $T:V\to V$ is a linear endomorphism of a vector space $V$ and $I:V\to V$ is the identity.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any special name for an operator or matrix of the form $\lambda I - T$ (or $cI - A$) in either linear algebra or functional analysis.  However, some possibilities are

- an *inverse of the resolvent*,
- a *pseudoinverse of the resolvent*, or
- a *pre-resolvent*.

All three of these are meant to capture the the notion that $cI - A$ has a relation to the resolvent operator, though the exact nature of that relation is a little delicate.  More context is provided below.

---

Given that endomorphisms of vector spaces are mentioned, it may be that much of the following is redundant for the asker.<sup>[1]</sup>  However, I think that the following discussion helps to justify the terminology suggested above.

In [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis), if $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space (a topological vector space possessing a complete norm) and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, then the [*resolvent operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory#Resolvent_operator) (corresponding to $T$ at $\lambda$) is defined to be
$$ R_{\lambda} := (\lambda I - T)^{-1}, $$
where $I$ is the identity operator.

The resolvent operator plays a special role in functional analysis:  the *resolvent set* of $T$ consists of all of the values of $\lambda$ such that $R_{\lambda}$ is a bounded linear operator (e.g. it exists and is bounded), while the *spectrum* of $T$ consists of all other values of $\lambda$.  In the case that $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then $T$ may be represented by an $n\times n$ matrix, and the spectrum of $T$ will correspond to the set of eigenvalues.  The Wikipedia article on [spectral theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory) offers a reasonable summary.

---

[1] And now that I have checked out the asker's profile, I am reasonably certain that the context is redundant.  However, it might be useful to others. ;)

Comment: What about "the *pseudoinverse* of the resolvent"? The genuine inverse of $c\cdot I_n-A$ doesn't exist when $c$ is an eigenvalue, but the pseudoinverse always exists.

Comment: Or would people object to calling the pseudoinverse of $c\cdot I_n-A$ the resolvent? I'm not particularly well-acquainted with the language of spectral theory!

Comment: I like pseudoinverse.  Or, perhaps, because the operator $\lambda - T$ is guaranteed to be defined and relatively well behaved (aside from potentially lacking an inverse) a *pre-resolvent*?  Unfortunately, I, too, am not an expert in spectral theory (though, frankly, I really ought to be better versed in it...), and I am unaware of any special term for this operator in that context.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I've edited the answer to include the new suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It is a specific type of linear [matrix pencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil).